# Outer automorphism groups of finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, automorphism-group

Is it known which finite groups are isomorphic to the outer automorphism group of some finite group?

If not, what can be said about such groups - that is, is there any known class of finite groups not isomorphic to the outer automorphism group of any finite group?

Comment: This has now been answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372480/is-every-finite-group-the-outer-automorphism-group-of-a-finite-group